# What is the piece and piece number of the rocket launcher accessory this Joker figure is holding?

Tags: part-identification

He is holding a rocket launcher type piece that I cannot identify.  What is the piece and piece number of the accessory this figure is holding?

[image: He Is Holding A Rocket Launcher Type Piece That I Cannot Identify.]

Comment: I suspect that the rocket launcher is made from more than one piece.

Answer (score 7):

[6195916: Function Element, Female](https://brickset.com/parts/6195916/function-element-female)

[image]

+

[306226: Round Brick 1X1](https://brickset.com/parts/306226/round-brick-1x1)

[image]

makes:

[image]